# Cannot modify User Roles in InfoPath

Tags: infopath, form, user, roles

I am trying to modify the User Roles for my form but the button 'User Roles' button in the Data tab is greyed out and I cannot click it. Anyone has any idea what might be the reason? I tried googling and binging it but nothing comes up.

Answer (score 1):

The User Roles can only be used in forms that are designed to be filled using the InfoPath Filler. Your InfoPath Form must have been designed to be filled using a Web Browser.

To check if your InfoPath Form would be filled in Web Browser or InfoPath Filler, follow these steps:

1. Click On File Tab and Click Form Options.
2. In the Category list, click Compatibility.
3. Check Form Type drop-down control.

If you change the Form Type to InfoPath Filler Form and go back to your form, you will find that User Roles button on the ribbon of Data tab is now enabled.

Comment: The 'form type' is workflow form but it is greyed out as well. Any idea how to change it? Thanks a lot for your feedback!